# i cant ping my host pc on my linux fs pad

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I compiled a native Linux kernel for my android pad, and it runs well ,also I build a simple file system which is contained of some basic commands.I configured network,but I met some problems, I cant ping my host pc.commands I used are wpa_supplicant,dhclient and ifconfig.i am sure my network is ok,who can help me

Comment: I can ping other devices connected my local network but the gateway

Comment: I would have asked this question [here](https://superuser.com/) or [there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

open in the command-line:

```
sudo /etc/config/network/interfaces
```

and check the configuration that your pc must be have the same address network like if your linux fs pad is192.168.1.1 your host get 192.168.1.12 for example and try to ping again.

Comment: thanks, but  only busybox and glibc on my Linux file system, no configuration files in etc menu, should I mkdir network and touch interfaces

Comment: open command-line and type sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces and enter

Answer (score 0):

finally, I find why I cant ping outside network, these days, wanna cry virsus corrupted may computers in my country, thus my school closed some ports. maybe the ping port was closed as well